# SQL Query References

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reference

I'm finishing up a *project* and part of the code says this:

```
EmergencyServicesRequiredID int references EmergencyServicesRequired(ID),
PeopleAffectedID int references PeopleAffected(ID)
```

what does "int references" mean exactly ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `references` key word in a `create table` statement is one way to express foreign key relationships.

A foreign key relationship says that the column `EmergencyServicesRequiredID` in the first table must be a valid value in the column `id` in the table `EmergencyServicesRequired`.  The database automatically does this check.  In addition, foreign key relationships can help the SQL engine optimize queries.